# cruisecontrol config.xml special characters svnbootstrapper

Tags: character, cruisecontrol

I have a line like :

```
  <svnbootstrapper LocalWorkingCopy="${projects.dir}/${project.name}" Password="4udr=qudafe$h$&e4Rub" Username="televic-education" />
```

in my config.xml. Because of special characters in the Password cruisecontrol service won't start. Is there a way to solve this?

Maybe with setting a property? Or escaping characters?

thx, Lieven Cardoen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace & with &amp; in the password attribute. I don't know if that's the problem, but it's definitely *a* problem.

Comment: This seems right to me.  If the service isn't starting it is probably an issue w/the xml parsing so & -> &amp; is worth trying.